# Check path between first and last rows of randomly updating matrix in O(1) time

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

We start with a nxn matrix filled with 0s. After each iteration a random cell of the matrix is chosen and changed to a 1. If an already changed cell is chosen again, it remains as a 1 and we proceed to choose a new random cell.

The objective is to determine after each iteration whether a path that connects the first and last rows of the matrix exists in O(1) time.

We define that a path consists of a set of neighbor cells of 1s. Two cells are neighbors if they are at most 1 square away from each other and they both contain a 1. For example, the (i,j)-th cell may have as its neighbor cells the following coordinates: (i-1, j-1), (i-1, j), (i-1, j+1), (i, j-1), (i, j+1), (i+1, j-1), (i+1, j) and (i+1, j+1). In other words, only those cells that surround it may become its neighbors and start forming a path with it.

I know there are algorithms to find such a path for a fixed matrix, but they take at least O(n^2) time. In order to achieve O(1) time I must use information from previous iterations, but so far I have only achieved O(n) time by recursively transversing all possible paths from the last changed cell.

I believe the use of efficient data structures would be suitable to achieve the desired O(1) time, but I'm not too well versed in that matter.

I would gladly appreciate if anyone could sketch an efficient algorithm to achieve this purpose or orientate me in some manner.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What would you want the Big O to be to find the path from start to finish?

Comment: The idea would be to keep information of the already existing paths. For example, the minimum and maximum row they reach to. Then, when a new cell is changed, you check whether that cell is neighbor to a path. If it is, then you add that cell to that path, and update the path's minimum or maximum. When any path's minimum row is the first one, and its maximum row is the last one, then you determine that a path connecting the first and last rows has been achieved. This must be done in O(1) for each iteration.

Comment: What terminates the iterations? Do you simply iterate until such a path is discovered?

Comment: That's correct. When a path connecting the first and last rows is discovered, we would terminate the iterations and print the final matrix with 0s and 1s.

Comment: The problem can be formulated in a way that lends itself to applying a disjoint-set data structure. However the worst case cost of merging disjoint sets would be O(log(N^2)) = O(log(N)), at least from what I can tell.  This is better than your current approach but doesn't quite meet the target constraint; maybe it can be improved to meet your target constraints, however.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have thought about the disjoint-set data structure, but I didn't manage to get the desired result. When a new path is created I create a disjoint-set object. Then I store a reference to that object in an auxiliary matrix to directly access that object and merge it with the a new neighbour cell's own disjoint-set object when required. However, I must also update the references in the auxiliary matrix to the newly merged object, but that could take O(N) time or worse. How would you employ the disjoint-set data structure to achieve the desired result in O(log(N))?

Comment: Off-topic: This can be simulated with "real world" material. Imagine a grid of square cells made of insulating material. At the bottom of each cell are 8 metal contacts. Each contact is wired to a contact in a neighboring cell. (5 wired for edge cells, 3 for corner cells.) The top contacts in the cells of the top row are wired to a battery terminal. The bottom contacts in the cells of the bottom row are wired to a buzzer. The other battery pole and contact on the buzzer are connected. Now, drop metal cubs at random into the cells until the buzzer sounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to saving whether a cell is "0" or "1", also add information on whether there's a path from the start to that cell. Then, when a new cell is added, you update all potential new neighbors to be visited. While such an update might be O(n) in the worst case (where `n` is the number of elements which is "1"), it will be amortized O(1) since each cell only gets updated this way once.

```java
record Cell(
    //false if it is "0", else true
    boolean active,
    //if there is a path from the start to this point
    boolean hasPath){}
```

```java
//just create an empty matrix of cells
private Cell[][] field = createEmptyField(YOUR_N);

private Cell[][] createEmptyField(int n){
    Cell[][] field = new Cell[n][n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            field[i][j]=new Cell(false, false);
        }
    }
    return field;
}

public void fillInRandomlyUntilPath(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY){
    Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    field[startX, startY] = new Cell(true, true);//assume the start is visited
    while(!field[endX][endY].hasPath()){//loop until there is a path to the end
        //everything here is amortized O(1)!
        //find new element
        int selectedX = random.nextInt(field.length);
        int selectedY = random.nextInt(field[selectedX].length);
        if(!field[selectedX][selectedY].active()){//if it's already "1", ignore it
            field[selectedX][selectedY] = new Cell(true, false);
            //we need to check all neighbours whether there's a path from the start to any of them
            forAllNeighbours(selectedX, selectedY, (x,y)->{
                if(field[x][y].hasPath()){
                    field[selectedX][selectedY] = new Cell(true, false);
                    setPath(selectedX, selectedY);//if there is a path, check it recursively
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
//this method sets hasPath to true for all neighbours recursively
private void setPath(int x,int y){
    if(field[x][y].active()&&!field[x][y].hasPath()){
        field[x][y]=new Cell(true, true);
        forAllNeighbours(x,y,this::setPath);
    }
}
//execute a function for all neighbours of a point
private void forAllNeighbours(int x, int y, IntBiConsumer exec){
    for(int i=Math.max(0,x-1);i<Math.min(field.length,x+2);i++){
        for(int j=Math.max(0,y-1);j<Math.min(field[i].length,y+2);j++){
            if(x!=i||y!=j){
                exec.accept(i,j);
            }
        }
    }
}

//BiConsumer<Integer,Integer> without boxing
@FunctionalInterface
private static interface IntBiConsumer{
    void accept(int first, int second);
}
```

If you don't know about amortized complexity, it means that previous calls can take longer than the wished complexity but it will have that complexity on average.

In this case, each cell is only "discovered" once. With discovering, I mean that `hasPath` is set to true. When that happens, it will check each neighbours which requires 9 (which is a constant) calls but further calls only happen for undiscovered cells.
For example, if the cells next to the start are activated last, it would do all the work of discovering the cells at once. However, this work is linear with respect to the number of iterations/activated cells and only needs to be done once.

If you run into `StackOverflowError`s (for bigger grids), you might want to change the `setPath` method to not use recursion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It will take me some time to review the code and understand it, but 0(1) amortized time is definitely good enough.

Comment: Note that it should only be amortized O(1) for what is inside the `while` loop. Also, note that I have corrected some mistakes I made (after actually running it).

Comment: +1. A related approach, which also gives amortized-constant time and will probably do a better job distributing the cost evenly, is to use a [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to track connectedness.

Comment: Your idea was brilliant dan1st! Although I've had some trouble reading through the code due to my inexpertise in Java and programming in general, I have implemented your algorithm to store a hasPath variable in every cell and update all its neighbors recursively when a cell with hasPath true comes into contact with another that has it false. Your argument that it has O(1) amortized time because every cell gets updated at most once is correct. I have run my own version of your algorithm with the previous O(n) program I was using and found it to be much faster. Thank you, your answer was 10/10.

Comment: @ruakh Feel free to write your own answer with that. I didn't feel distributing the costs more evenly would be necessary in this case. Also, for measuring the complexity, you could also count the number of iterations in `forAllNeighbours` and divide them by the number of iterations of the outermost `while` loop. This should be more or less constant (but you might run into `StackOverflowError`s.

Comment: @dan1stiscrying: Re: "Feel free to write your own answer with that": I don't see a need for that; this answer is fine. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

I will leave here my own program based on dan1st's idea to keep track of every cell's path information and O(1) amortized time to update it until a path of type '1' cells that connects the first and last row is achieved.

```java
public class RandomMatrix {
    
    int n;
    boolean pathExists;
    Cell[][] Matrix;
    int[][] neighborCoords = {{-1,-1}, {-1,0}, {-1,1}, {0,-1}, {0,1}, {1,-1}, {1,0}, {1,1}};
    

    // Cell object which will store whether it is a type '1' cell or not, and whether it belongs to a path that connects the first and/or last rows.

    class Cell {
        boolean filled, topPath, bottomPath;
        public Cell (boolean filled, boolean topPath, boolean bottomPath) {
            this.filled = filled;
            this.topPath = topPath;
            this.bottomPath = bottomPath;
        }
    }


    // Creates an nxn matrix of cells type '0'.

    public void CreateEmptyMatrix(int n) {
        this.n = n;
        pathExists = false;
        Matrix = new Cell[n][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                Matrix[i][j] = new Cell(false, false, false);
            }
        }
    }
    

    // Changes the i,j-th cell to type '1' and updates path variables.

    public void FillCell(int i, int j) {
        if (!Matrix[i][j].filled) {
            Matrix[i][j].filled = true;
            if (i == 0) {
                Matrix[i][j].topPath = true;
            } else if (i == n-1) {
                Matrix[i][j].bottomPath = true;
            }
            UpdatePathVariables(i,j);
        }
    }
    

    // Updates path variables of the i,j-th cell and its neighbor cells. If anything was updated, it recursively calls the method again on the neighbor cell.
    // If a cell is updated, we check whether it is connected to the first and last rows and update the pathExists variable accordingly.
    // Each cell will be updated at most once, which ensures O(1) amortized time of the algorithm for each random fill of a cell.
    // A second loop is necessary in some cases to ensure correct update of every neighbor cell's path variables.
    
    public void UpdatePathVariables(int i, int j) {
        boolean keepUpdating = true;
        int loops = 1;
        while(keepUpdating & loops <= 2) {
            keepUpdating = false;
            for (int[] coord: neighborCoords) {
                int a = i+coord[0];
                int b = j+coord[1];
                if (a>=0 && a < n && b >=0 && b < n) {
                    if (Matrix[a][b].filled && (Matrix[a][b].bottomPath != Matrix[i][j].bottomPath || Matrix[a][b].topPath != Matrix[i][j].topPath)) {
                        if (Matrix[a][b].topPath && !Matrix[i][j].topPath) {
                            Matrix[i][j].topPath = true;
                            keepUpdating = true;
                        }
                        if (Matrix[a][b].bottomPath && !Matrix[i][j].bottomPath) {
                            Matrix[i][j].bottomPath = true;
                            keepUpdating = true;
                        }
                        if (Matrix[i][j].topPath && !Matrix[a][b].topPath) {
                            Matrix[a][b].topPath = true;
                        }
                        if (Matrix[i][j].bottomPath && !Matrix[a][b].bottomPath) {
                            Matrix[a][b].bottomPath = true;
                        }
                        if (Matrix[i][j].topPath && Matrix[i][j].bottomPath) {
                            pathExists = true;
                            return;
                        }
                        UpdatePathVariables(a,b);
                    }
                }
            }
            loops++;
        }
    }


    // Returns true if a path between the first and last row of the matrix composed of type '1' cells has been achieved.

    public boolean PathExists() {
        return pathExists;
    }


    // toString Override to print the final matrix of 1s and 0s.
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String str = "";
        int value;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (Matrix[i][j].filled) {
                    value = 1;
                } else {
                    value = 0;
                }
                str += value;
            }
            str += "\n";
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Here is a main class to test the program.

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class MainClass {

    static int seed = 1;
    static int n = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rng = new Random(seed);
        RandomMatrix matrix = new RandomMatrix();  
        matrix.CreateEmptyMatrix(n);
        while(!matrix.PathExists()) {
            int i = rng.nextInt(n);
            int j = rng.nextInt(n);
            matrix.FillCell(i,j);
        }            
        System.out.println(matrix);
    }
}
```

I have verified that the program works as intended and that it achieves O(1) amortized time for each FillCell(i,j) call (O(n^2) time as a whole until a path between first and last rows is achieved).

Huge thanks to everyone that answered!